# How to fix Null Pointer exceptions

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I need help setting the text of the label in my main.view.fxml to the current hour, minute and second as it's throwing a nullpointer exception

```
What I tried so far:
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
HRS_lbl.setText(String.valueOf(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR)));
MIN_lbl.setText(String.valueOf(calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE)));
SEC_lbl.setText(String.valueOf(calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND)));
```

But its not working...

**This is my fxml file**

```
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.effect.Blend?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.LinearGradient?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.Stop?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="209.0" prefWidth="758.0" style="-fx-background-color: #227B89;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/9.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="lecture.application.mainViewController">
   <children>
      <FlowPane orientation="VERTICAL" prefHeight="209.0" prefWidth="273.0" style="-fx-background-color: #1F1F1F;" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0">
         <effect>
            <Blend />
         </effect>
         <children>
            <AnchorPane prefHeight="209.0" prefWidth="276.0">
               <children>
                  <Label layoutX="65.0" layoutY="80.0" text="The Clock">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="34.0" />
                     </font>
                     <textFill>
                        <LinearGradient endX="1.0" endY="1.0">
                           <stops>
                              <Stop color="#e0e3ebcc" />
                              <Stop color="#e0e3ebcc" offset="0.32950191570881227" />
                              <Stop color="WHITE" offset="1.0" />
                           </stops>
                        </LinearGradient>
                     </textFill>
                  </Label>
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
         </children>
      </FlowPane>
      <Label fx:id="HRS_lbl" layoutX="360.0" layoutY="49.0" text="00">
         <font>
            <Font name="Consolas Bold" size="35.0" />
         </font>
         <padding>
            <Insets left="20.0" top="20.0" />
         </padding>
      </Label>
      <Label fx:id="MIN_lbl" layoutX="453.0" layoutY="49.0" text="00">
         <font>
            <Font name="Consolas Bold" size="35.0" />
         </font>
         <padding>
            <Insets left="20.0" top="20.0" />
         </padding>
      </Label>
      <Label fx:id="SEC_lbl" layoutX="559.0" layoutY="49.0" prefHeight="61.0" prefWidth="82.0" text="00">
         <font>
            <Font name="Consolas Bold" size="35.0" />
         </font>
         <padding>
            <Insets left="20.0" top="20.0" />
         </padding>
      </Label>
      <Label layoutX="390.0" layoutY="123.0" text="HRS" />
      <Label layoutX="483.0" layoutY="117.0" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="28.0" text="MIN" />
      <Label layoutX="591.0" layoutY="123.0" text="SEC" />
      <Button fx:id="exit_btn" layoutX="690.0" layoutY="6.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Exit" textFill="#000000fa" />
   </children>
   <opaqueInsets>
      <Insets />
   </opaqueInsets>
</AnchorPane>
```

**This is the error it is showing** 
 Is this warning critical : WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of 
  version 9.0.1 by JavaFX runtime of version 8.0.161

```
Apr 23, 2018 10:34:47 PM javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement processValue
WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 9.0.1 by JavaFX runtime of version 8.0.161
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at lecture.application.mainViewController$1.run(mainViewController.java:39)
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$154(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at lecture.application.mainViewController.setTime(mainViewController.java:51)
    at lecture.application.Main.start(Main.java:41)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$161(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$174(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    ... 1 more
```

**This is the main class**

So the error is starting at line 39 where i am starting to setText to the 
label in my fxml file

```
private Stage primaryStage;
private AnchorPane mainLayout;
double x;
double y;   

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
    this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
    this.primaryStage.setTitle("The Clock ");
    this.primaryStage.setResizable(true);
    this.primaryStage.setMaximized(false);
    this.primaryStage.setAlwaysOnTop(false);
    this.primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
    mainViewController controler = new mainViewController();

    primaryStage.maximizedProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        if (newValue)
            primaryStage.setMaximized(false);
    });
    showMainView();
    controler.setTime();
    setDrag();
}

private void showMainView() throws IOException {
    try {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("main.view.fxml"));
        mainLayout = loader.load();

        Scene scene = new Scene(mainLayout);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();}

    catch(Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

void setDrag() {     
    mainLayout.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent arg0) {
            x = arg0.getSceneX();
            y = arg0.getSceneY();
        }
    });

    mainLayout.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            primaryStage.setX(event.getSceneX() - x);
            primaryStage.setY(event.getSceneY() - y);
        }
    });  
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

**This is the fxml Controller class**

```
@FXML
private Label HRS_lbl;

@FXML
private Label MIN_lbl;

@FXML
private Label SEC_lbl;

@FXML
private Button exit_btn;

void setTime() {
    new Thread () {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
                HRS_lbl.setText(String.valueOf(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR)));
                MIN_lbl.setText(String.valueOf(calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE)));
                SEC_lbl.setText(String.valueOf(calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND)));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.getMessage();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }.start();

    exit_btn.setOnAction(new javafx.event.EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Thank you for using The Clock...... developed By Tawanda Mavondo");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: its my first time posting on Stackoverflow

Comment: ;) yes i know that. Its just a friedly advice how you will get your problem solved.

Comment: You create a controller instance that isn't used with a fxml. You need to get the controller instance after loading a fxml with a non-static load method of a `FXMLLoader` instance. Furthermore nodes shouldn't be updated from a background thread. getting a calendar instance is hardly a long-running operation so running the code on a seperate thread does not provide any benefit... BTW: it seems like you could simply move the code of the `setTime` method to a method `@FXML private void initialize()` which is called by `FXMLLoader` after it's done injecting all fields.

Comment: Avoid mixing Swing with JavaFX.  Use [Alert](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/Alert.html), not JOptionPane.

Comment: and while you are at reading: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them - without you are confusing others and yourself :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It's all about your controller

*You take an object for a controller but it's reference has no relation with your VIEW (FXML)

you can add whatever you want to do in your controller and use initialize function which start after render view that's mean it will be start immediately .

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
setTime() ;
}
```

I test it it works fine

Attention:you are using MVC design pattern .